# Is the extra damage die from Orcish Fury affected by crits?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, feats

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, there is a racial feat called [Orcish Fury][1] on page 75 that reads:

> When you hit with an attack using a simple or martial weapon, you can roll one of the weapon’s damage dice an additional time and add it as extra damage of the weapon’s damage type.

Is this extra damage die affected by critical hits? Because I can see two interpretations of this feat.

Assuming a Greataxe critical hit:

A.) 1d12[base] + 1d12[crit] + 1d12[Orcish Fury]

B.) 2d12[base + Orcish Fury] + 2d12[crit]

**Which of these calculations is correct for the damage on a crit?**

Comment: related: [How does extra damage work for critical hits?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58118)

Answer (score 24):

## You get 2d12 extra damage from the critical hit (option B)

The PHB says:

> If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well.

Orcish Fury's extra damage is by definition "other damage dice" so it definitely applies.

Further evidence can be seen by comparing the wording to sneak attack.

Sneak attack says:

> ...you can deal an **extra 1d6 damage** to one creature you hit with an attack

Which is almost identical to the wording in Orcish Fury:

> add it as **extra damage** of the weapon’s damage type

So, if sneak attack's extra damage is doubled on a critical hit so should the extra damage from Orcish Fury.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/741455783339003904) seems to support this ruling as well when he said:

> When you score a critical hit, roll **all of the attack's damage dice** again, no matter the source of the dice.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/964664039442804736) has also now given a direct ruling for this which agrees with all of the above:

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll the attack's damage dice an additional time. If the attack involves extra dice—from a feature like Orcish Fury or Sneak Attack—you roll those an additional time too.

Comment: Yep. If the ability/feature specifies that it deals extra damage on top of an existing attack, you double it if the attack is a critical hit. Relevant part of the description of crits: "For example, if you score a critical hit with a Dagger, roll 2d4 for the damage, rather than 1d4, and then add your relevant ability modifier. If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well."

Answer (score 7):

Option B but you also forgot to add the Half-Orc racial 'Savage Attacks'.

If you are willing to wait for a critical to dump your Orcish Fury, you will get;

- 2d12 Base
- 2d12 Orcish Fury
- 1d12 Savage Attacks

For an average of 32.5 Damage + bonuses.