# How does the UA Centaur's Charge ability interact with critical hits?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, unearthed-arcana, critical-hit, racial-traits

The UA Centaur (from [Unearthed Arcana: Centaurs and Minotaurs](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf)) has the Charge ability:

> ***Charge.*** If you move at least 20 feet straight toward a target and then hit it   with a melee weapon attack on the same turn, **roll the weapon’s damage dice twice and  add them together.** Once you   use this ability, you can’t use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

**How does this ability interact with a critical hit?** Does it triple the weapon damage or quadruple it?

Comment: I'm aware that Ravnica has Centaur official race and is different with the UA, but I'm mainly interested if there is another ability with similar wording and how it should interact with critical hit.

Comment: Just in case anyone's curious, the Charge trait was changed to the following when the centaur was published in the Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica: "If you move at least 30 feet straight toward a target and then hit it with a melee weapon attack on the same turn, you can immediately follow that attack with a bonus action, making one attack against the target with your hooves."

Comment: Related: [Is the extra damage die from Orcish Fury affected by crits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115358/is-the-extra-damage-die-from-orcish-fury-affected-by-crits). Another question about the same trait: [Does the playable UA Centaur's Charge racial feature affect both attacks if I have the extra attack feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123480/does-the-playable-ua-centaurs-charge-racial-feature-affect-both-attacks-if-i-ha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A crit triples the number of rolls of the weapon's dice.

PHB, p. 196:

> **Roll all of the attack's damage dice twice** and add them together.
> [...]
> To speed up play you can roll all the damage dice at once.

The number of weapon damage dice does not increase for a critical hit, so the additional dice rolls of centaur's *Charge* ability are the same as for an attack that does not crit.

Rolling *"all the damage dice at once"* is just a way to speed up play; it's not how the number of damage dice is determined.